# how to get appDelegate with Urban AirShip (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, urbanairship.com

After integrating Urban Airship, when I call

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate
```

I always get nil. When I tried to get class of UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate, it tells me, that it is UAAppDelegateProxy now.

But

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? UAAppDelegateProxy
```

also returns nil.

How can I get my appDelegate?

**Edit**

I figured up, that this happens only when `UAConfig` parameter `automaticSetupEnabled` is set to true. When `automaticSetupEnabled` is false, I get appDelegate as usual, but I'm losing advantages of urban airship automatic configuration.

Comment: For anyone Googling, I had a similar problem where using the Localytics autoIntegrate function was causing sharedApplication().delegate to return a LLAppDelegateProxy instead of the real thing. Removing Localytics fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Urban Airship SDK that they have promised to fix in the next SDK release.

From their support:

> We are aware of this issue and are looking to have it resolved in our
>   next SDK release. In the meantime, as a workaround, manually setting
>   up our SDK will allow you to work with the AppDelegate successfully.